# How to disable unity side panel after cairo-dock install?

Tags: unity, 16.04, cairo-dock

So i recently installed cairo-dock and is very satisfied.

Is there any way i can disable the side panel or at least the bouncing 'feature'?

Video of the problem: https://vid.me/dsln

Picture of bounce in hidden unity panel:

[image: Picture of bounce in hidden unity panel]

Comment: What do you mean by "bounce" feature , by the way ?

Comment: Just below my "Behind" icon in chromium you can see a small alarm clock icon bouncing. Thats the thing i want to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Compiz configuration settings manager (CCSM) and go to the:

```
Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Launcher
```

and set "Hide Animation" to the "Fade Only" and after that the opening application icons don't slide at all.

Maybe it seems weird, but it's the thing you must do to disable that behavior.

Comment: Solved my problem!!

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to go into System Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior and set launcher to autohide with lowest reveal sensitivity

[image]

If you find that reveal sensitivity is not low enough , you can go into command line and set sensitivity to something absurdly low:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/edge-responsiveness 0.00001
```

Comment: Just below my "Behind" icon in chromium you can see a small alarm clock icon bouncing. Thats the thing i want to hide.